# Visual Studio unresolved symbol _InterlockedCompareExchange

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, sqlite

I'm porting some C code from GCC into Visual C++ and I'm running into this error when trying to add SQLite3 as a static lib.

I've compiled SQLite as another Visual Studio project, but when I try to add sqlite3.lib in Properties->Liner->"Additional Dependencies" I get the following error:

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _InterlockedCompareExchange | File sqlite3.lib(sqlite3.obj)

It seems to be referring to [this function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683560(v=vs.85).aspx), but that's a bit over my head.

Thanks!

Comment: This might be an issue with C++ name mangling, but I'd have to go and look at the kernel32 headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite's system call redirection mechanism tries to access `InterlockedCompareExchange` through a function pointer. This does not work on x64 architectures, where it is a macro.

This is fixed ([[1]](http://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/info/7be244ce129d6502f3a3e3f3e8a1dd61ef71d878), [[2]](http://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/info/ab1a751e1304749bef5bc5c833f9abed8950f7d0)) in version 3.8.6.